# Store thrown exception for CONCURRENT_MAP_REMOVE while using Hazelcast (Java)

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast -2.5 in a cluster.  I am trying to load an ArrayList of User defined objects (with a few String fields and one Integer) in the store-load implementation of my Hazelcast Map (String, ArrayList).  The initial load all does not give me any exceptions.  However, if the load gets invoked due to a get call on the map for a key for which there is no value in the map (and hence the load gets called), I see the following exception being thrown (I am also doing a remove operation on the map after that point in time):

```
Store thrown exception for CONCURRENT_MAP_REMOVE
```

It gives me a class cast exception stating that my UD Object cannot be cast to a String.  I would not be surprised if I missed something in my implementation - its just that when this call is made, I am trying to do a get operation on the map and assigning the result to an ArrayList of User Defined Object.  The load operation in the store-load also returns an ArrayList of User defined object (the store-load is declared in the same way).

```
WARNING: [192.168.1.1]:5703 [dev] Store thrown exception for CONCURRENT_MAP_REMOVE
java.lang.ClassCastException: models.test.TestClass cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at models.test.StoreLoadTestMap.load(StoreLoadTestMap.java:1)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.concurrentmap.MapStoreWrapper.load(MapStoreWrapper.java:143)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager$RemoveOperationHandler$RemoveLoader.doMapStoreOperation(ConcurrentMapManager.java:2681)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ConcurrentMapManager$AbstractMapStoreOperation.run(ConcurrentMapManager.java:3860)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.executor.ParallelExecutorService$ParallelExecutorImpl$ExecutionSegment.run(ParallelExecutorService.java:212)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.hazelcast.impl.ExecutorThreadFactory$1.run(ExecutorThreadFactory.java:38)
```

Any ideas on troubleshooting this?

Comment: I need to confirm but it seems like I'll get this exception if the arraylist being returned from the load operation (in the store-load implementation) is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you will get this exception if the arraylist being returned from the hazelcast load operation (in the store-load implementation) is empty.